# Creating a shared folder programmatically c#

Tags: c#, winforms, share

I am trying to create the shared folder in computer management shares with the following code

```
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            ManagementBaseObject outParams;
            inParams["Description"] = Description;
            inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
            inParams["Path"] = FolderPath;
            inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive
            outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
            var res = (uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
```

res always returns 2.

Can anyone be of help in this regard?
What does it 2 mean and what are all the other output parameters?

Comment: "2" means *Access denied*. [Win32_Share](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435(v=vs.85).aspx#methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Create method of  Win32_Share documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389393(v=vs.85).aspx) , possible return values are :

> Success (0)
>
> Access denied (2)
>
> Unknown failure (8)
>
> Invalid name (9)
>
> Invalid level (10)
>
> Invalid parameter (21)
>
> Duplicate share (22)
>
> Redirected path (23)
>
> Unknown device or directory (24)
>
> Net name not found (25)
>
> Other (26–4294967295)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting 9 (invalid name) now. any idea?

Comment: Check your folder path.